# Initialize Class Object to Referenced Memory

Tags: c++, class, pointers, reference, initialization

Here's the gist of what I'm trying to do.

- I have a program that is complex enough that I want to organize it into a set of header files
- The program needs to keep a large class object in memory, available to all functions
- The class definition is thus in its own header file (since other header files independently use it)
- Include guards I set up seem to be working, so the class is only defined once for the entire file
- The class data itself has an unknown size at compile time. I'm reading the contents of data files into the structure, and the file is chosen by the user at run time
- So, I first initialize the class object as empty, within the main scope of my program. Then, I want to pass a pointer to this newly-created class instance to a function which reads file data.
- The file-read function should allocate enough memory to contain all the data in the file, and subsequently write to the memory referred to by the class pointer.
- I want the data set to be saved within the main scope, and not passed by value.

Maybe this dummy code will better illustrate what I want to do.

```
#include <class_def.h>
#include <readfile.h>
#include <otherfunctions.h> // Will perform a calculation based on class data in memory

myclass data;

int main()
{
    read_to_memory(&data);
    some_other_function(&data);
}

--------------------

int read_to_memory(myclass* data_pt) // Function from readfile.h
{
    // Get filename from user input
    // Determine filesize, from which the size of class members is derived
    // Then initialize class object referred to by data_pt
    *data_pt = myclass.myclass(size);

    // Then, start writing to memory with file data
    // Is actually a big "for" loop
    (*data_pt).member1[0] = <value read from file>;
    (*data_pt).member2[0] = <value read from file>;
    ...
    (*data_pt).member1[N] = <value read from file>;
    (*data_pt).member2[N] = <value read from file>;
}
```

Right now, I'm running into seg faults when I try to access the class members from the read_into_memory function. Attempting either a read

```
cout << (*data_pt).member1[0])
```

or a write

```
(*data_pt).member1[0] = <value read from file>;
```

does this. However, the crashes do occur after the line: "*data_pt = myclass.myclass(size);", which suggest to me that the class constructor is working...

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to show the code for myclass.

Answer (score 3):

```
*data_pt = myclass.myclass(size);
```

should not compile.

Use a standard library collection class such as `std::vector` to hold your data.

Answer (score 1):

Please use some sane C++ STL collection to hold the data such as a `list`, `map`, or `deque`. Don't try to fake it somehow, it's just not worth it.